# How to integrate a .jsx file to .js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I m new with React programming and coding in JS. I have a landing page in React with code in .JS.

I want to update the landing page with antd landing (https://landing.ant.design/). With this I get .jsx files.

I want to integrate them to the previous .js file.

Example: index.js

```
const LandingPage = () => {

return (
    <main className='landing'>

        <Navbar />

        <Page>

        </Page>

        <Footer />
    </main>
   );
  };
 export default LandingPage;
```

Then I want to incorporate the index.jsx that antd gives me.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have install all need dependencies(assume you use create-react-app)

[Dependencies](https://landing.ant.design/docs/use/create-react-app#Dependencies)

and maybe you need add css preprocessor .less file support then rewrite config.

after did this, just import the index.jsx.